# How do QSelectionModel indexes work?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a list view that uses a proxy model and this code:

```
lastCurrRow = self.listView.selectionModel().currentIndex().row() #last row currently selected
last = self.proxyModel.rowCount() - 1                             #last row in view
print("lastCurrRow = %d\nlast = %d" %(lastCurrRow, last))
```

When the last item in the list view is selected, I get output like

```
lastCurrRow = 100
last = 100
```

But if I select any other row, say the second last row, I get output like

```
lastCurrRow = 96
last = 100
```

Should I be looking for a bug in my code somewhere or is this normal? Are the QModelIndexes from a QSelectionModel inherently different that the ones for the proxy model? I had been successfully using these lines of code without actually checking what they returned, but now I'm trying to do something slightly different and discovered this oddity.

Note: I'm not asking for help with my code, I just want a better understanding of how QSelectionModel works.

UPDATE: Turns out I didn't actually need those lines for what I was trying to do. I'd still like to know the reasoning behind the output I was getting though.